For all cardinals $\kappa, \lambda$ with $\lambda \geq cf(\kappa)$ the inequality $\kappa^{\lambda} > \kappa$ holds
I genuinely have no idea why the proposition in the title holds or how to show it. I am kind of new to cardinals and ordinals and very confused. If someone could explain, I would really appreciate that because I actually want to understand. TIA

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/K%C3%B6nig's_theorem_(set_theory)

But that is only for cardinals $\kappa \geq \aleph_0$, no?

@metamathics Yes, it fails when $\kappa$ is nonzero and finite and $\lambda = 1.$

Does this answer your question? How to show $\kappa^{cf(\kappa)}>\kappa$?

@metamathics (not sure why I stipulated nonzero above…  it fails for $\kappa=0$ and $\lambda=1$ too. I guess I just meant that $\kappa^{cf \kappa} >\kappa$ holds when $\kappa=0$. Anyway, worrying about finite cardinals is not usually important here, which is probably why the statement you saw missed this.)

@spaceisdarkgreen Thanks, that may have helped. I'm still a little confused about all of this so I'm not quite sure if I understand but maybe it gets better with time.

@metamathics It would help if you could be more precise about what exactly is confusing you.
